# File structure of EDB file

Tags: database, exchange-server, edb

I have an offline .EDB file (exchange Database) that I want to pull information from such as the Computer name and the Flags etc. I have found the following offsets from `http://www.edbsearch.com/edb.html` which indicate that the Computer name etc comes from byte `0x24   0x10` However, looking at the following EDB file in 101 editor, the value appears to be non existent. It appears later on within the file, but not in a constant place.

Is there a constant byte that I can reliably pull the Computer name from the .EDB file ?  I am working on backups from another computer, but all of the solutions that I have found are for Live versions of .EDB files - which are useless for myself as I have offline databases.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With database replication (CCR in 2007, DAGs in 2010+), the concept of a computer name isn't that helpful. After a failover/switchover, what should the computer name be?

I don't think that the Computer Name is populated anymore. If `eseutil.exe -mh` doesn't report it, then it's not there.

Also check out JetGetDatabaseFileInfo. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg269239(v=exchg.10).aspx Note that the documentation is for esent.dll (Windows), and that ese.dll (Exchange) is not documented. While esent.dll and ese.dll are very similar, and for simple things (such as this) you can treat them similarly and get away with it, they are NOT identical, and you will sometimes come upon incompatibilities. In other words: Do it at your own risk, your mileage may vary, etc. etc. :)

-martin